# $K/k$ field extension, $[K:k]=p$ prime, $f(X)\in [X]$ has degree $p+1$, $f$ has root in $K\iff f$ has root in $k$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K/k$ a field extension, $[K:k]=p$ prime, $f(X)\in [X]$ with degree $\deg(f)= p+1$, so $f$ has root in $K\iff f$ has root in $k$.

As $k\subset K$, the $\Leftarrow$ implication is trivial. Any hints to the $\Rightarrow$ implication? I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one **Hint**:

If $\xi\in K$ is a root of $f$, consider the subextension 
$$k\subset k(\xi)\subset K$$
and remember the degree of extensions is multiplicative.

Comment: Ok, so $p=[K:k]=[K:k(\alpha)][k(\alpha):k]$. Since $p$ is prime, $[K:k(\alpha)]=p$ or $[k(\alpha):k]=p$. If $[K:k(\alpha)]=p$, $[k(\alpha):k]=1\implies \alpha\in k$. But what if $[k(\alpha):k]=p$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Silly me! I messed with all those multiplicativity, divisibility, &c. I'll delete it in a moment.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, can you help me with my comment, please? I would really appreciate that